# After each Package.json update app cannot load newly hashed index.js Vite PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, vite, workbox

I have just installed the vite-plugin-pwa and followed the documentation and have the following in my config

```
 VitePWA( { 
      injectRegister: 'auto',
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true
      },
      strategies: 'generateSW',
      workbox: {
        globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,html,ico,png,svg,mp3}'],
        sourcemap: true
      },
      includeAssets: ['favicon.ico', 'apple-touch-icon.png', 'masked-icon.svg'],
      manifest: {
        name: 'Litreach',
        short_name: 'Cluiche Litrithe',
        start_url: "/",
        display: "standalone",
        lang: "ga",
        description: 'Cluiche litrithe ina mbíonn ar an imreoir 5 fhocal a litriú gach lá. Cluintear na focail a rá sna 3 canúintí agus bíonn 5 iarracht agat an focal a litriú i gceart.',
        theme_color: '#ffffff',
        icons: [
          {
            src: 'pwa-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png',
            "purpose": "maskable"
          },
          {
            src: 'pwa-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png',
            "purpose": "any"
          },
          {
            src: 'pwa-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png'
          }
        ],
        dir: "ltr",
        orientation: "portrait",
        display_override: [
          "standalone"
        ],
        categories: [
          "education",
          "games"
        ]
      }
    })
```

However each time I bump the the package.json version number, the next time I go to load the app the application falls over.  When I inspect the Network key I can see that the app is trying to load `index.js?oldHashNumber` and the only way I can get the app to load is manually pressing the refresh button on the browser.

I believe there is some problem with the Service Worker or my PWA configuration.

Should I try to destroy the Service Worker and all their caches and start again?
If so how should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I found out that there is a setting that controls the max size of files included in precache manifest.
https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/guide/faq.html#missing-assets-from-sw-precache-manifest

In my case js bundle was exceeding 2mb and setting

```
injectManifest: {
  maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 6000000
}
```

helped me.

Comment: Lifesaver! I had some files just over 3MB and this fixed it. It is just a temporary bandaid, however, as 3MB feels quite large for a JS file. The "right" long-term solution for my project involves using [react-router's `lazy` option](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/lazy) more wisely, and perhaps breaking out certain third-party modules such as Mapbox into their own chunks.